# How vs. how much as an intensifier

Tags: intensifying-adverbs

Here's an exclamation:

> How you've grown!

And here's what *how* means according to the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/how):

> used to express a strong feeling such as surprise about the extent of something

Can we come to the conclusion that the above exclamation was originally "How *much* you've grown!", which has been simplified during history of English language?

Here's a similar case from [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/like):

> How do you like living in London (=how much do you like it)?

Comment: _How_ in this sense means _to what extent_ or _to what degree._ I don't see any necessity for _much_ to have always formed part of the phrase.

Comment: Compare to: "How sweet of you!" or "How lovely!"

Comment: 'How do you spell _syzygy_?' is obviously asking about manner, not extent. But 'How nice to see you!' is obviously an intensifier usage (cf '[It's] **very** nice to see you').  One can't see this as a deleted form of say 'How much nice to see you!' I'd say the suggested shift is unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we come to the conclusion that the above exclamation was originally "How much you've grown!",

No.

**How** is an adverb. Its meaning, in this context, is as shown below,

Thus in the expression of surprise, "How you have grown!" = "to what an extent you have grown!"

OED:

> **7.a. In what a way! to what an extent or degree!**
>
> 1808   W. Scott Marmion iii. vi. 139   *How pale his cheek, his eye how bright.*
>
> 1899   N.E.D. at How   Mod. colloq. *How you do like to tease one!*
>
> **11. Chiefly qualifying an adjective or adverb (also with verb like, etc.): To what extent; in what degree.**
>
> 1891   E. Peacock Narcissa Brendon I. 11   *You know how small my estate is.*

Comment: Actually, _how_ is a _Wh_-word, a pro-quantifier that refers to manner, means, or degree. It can modify any predicate (_how sick, how bad, how many, how much_). The exclamatory How is probly just that -- an interjection. LIke the _what_ in _What a good dog!_

Comment: @JohnLawler - I'm not convinced that "what" is an interjection in *"What a good dog"* Interjections are *usually* capable of being followed by an exclamation mark "What! You doubt my word?" In "What the devil are you doing?", what is an interrogative pronoun, and "the devil", an oath, which can be omitted.

Comment: Interjections are all unique; there isn't any "usually" because they're oral and nobody's counting. But call it a pronoun or an adverb if you want to. POS are really irrelevant outside of computing.

Comment: *Interjections are all unique* then they are much the same as other words, which are also unique in their own way. *But call it a pronoun or an adverb if you want to.* It is the OP who wishes to call it something. *POS are really irrelevant outside of computing* No. They help student understand and learn and compare words and expressions in their own language.