# Is the origin of the use of the word "how" as an intensifier the bible?

Tags: etymology, intensifying-adverbs

Taken literally, the phrase "how lovely!" is sort of odd, as "how" is just serving as a substitute for "so" or "very".
Wondering if this came about from a famous hebrew phrase from the psalms "Hine ma tov" ('behold how good').  "Ma" and "how" are pretty much synonymous and again doesn't seem at all obvious to go from use of "how" as an adjective meaning "in what manner" to intensifier.

Comment: Partially addressed at [How vs How much as an intensifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569471/how-vs-how-much-as-an-intensifier).

Comment: The Old English for "how" is "hu". ("Hu bismerlic!" How ridiculous!) There seems to be no obvious connection with Hebrew at all.

Comment: The only etymology I can find for an interjection usage is for the 'used in representations of Native American speech' standalone greeting sense.

Comment: Agreeing with the others here, I don't think it's any more biblical than Jar-Jar Binks' use of "How rude." It looks like the Hebrew equivalent is *mâ*. Rather, it seems like just taking a rhetorical-question idiom ("Well now, how nice was that of Auntie Mae to bring that pie over?") and inverting it back into a statement.

Answer (score 2):

*How* in this context doesn't exactly mean *very*, it's an exclamation at the degree to which the thing is 'lovely' or 'good'. Nothing odd about it -  I'm sure similar expressions exist in many languages other than English and Hebrew.

> How kind of you!
>
> How dark it is in here!
>
> How silly of me!

Comment: "How High the Moon"

Comment: "How *kind* of you to let me come."

Comment: In Spanish one uses not _Como_ 'how?' for such an exclamation, but _Qué_. with an accent, meaning 'what?' (_que_ without an accent is a complementizer like the _that_ in _He thinks that it's ready_).